# Neo4j Cypher query anomaly

Tags: neo4j

I have a very strange Cypher situation.
If I run the query

```
MATCH (n:label1)--(e:label2)--(i:label3) 
WHERE n.Uri = "someId" AND i.Name = "SomeName" 
RETURN i
```

nothing returns.
however if I add a named relationship

```
MATCH (n:label1)--(e:label2)-[:namedRelationship]-(i:label3) 
WHERE n.Uri = "someId" AND i.Name = "SomeName" 
RETURN i
```

I get a result returned.

This seems impossible, and looks like a very worrying bug, can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?
(NOTE - I've had to rename the Labels and Relationship for IP reasons)

Comment: Was the DB written to between the 2 calls?

Comment: No and it is repeatable

Comment: And if you write the relationship as -[]- ... does that return the result ?

Comment: Also ... what version of Neo4j are you running ?

Comment: Show an example of the data on which we can repeat this behavior. And what version of the database is used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I don't name the relationship, i.e. use -- or -[]-, no results are returned. I'm running version 3.2.0 , unfortunately I can't share the data set due to Intellectual Property issues